# Iterating over array in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyhYm.png)Hi I want to iterate over following array using angular2

```
let list = [{"-1" : [{a : 1, b: 2, c: 2}, {a:3, b: 4, c: 2}]},
            {"0" : [{a : 12, b: 32, c: 22}, {a:31, b: 24, c: 32}}]
```

And show the out put in a table formate as shown in the image

please help me in solving the problem.

Following code i have tried

```
<table >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th > a </th>
    <th > b </th>
    <th > c </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
  <tr *ngFor="let element of list">
           <td> {{element['-1'].a}}</td>
           <td> {{element['-1'].b}}</td>
           <td> {{element['-1'].c}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

But i am not able to add the row "-1", "0"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What have you tried and where have you failed?

Comment: @ dfsq its a typo error please check now.

Comment: its an array inside an array. You are iterating only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you reformatted data a little bit:

```javascript
let list = [
  {"-1" : [{a : 1, b: 2, c: 2}, {a:3, b: 4, c: 2}]},
  {"0" : [{a : 12, b: 32, c: 22}, {a:31, b: 24, c: 32}}
]

this.list = list.map(item => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item)
  return {
    header: keys[0],
    data: item[keys[0]]
  }
})
```

Then you will need to render it with two loops. Maybe like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="list">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="header">
        <td colspan="3">{{ item.header }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of item.data">
        <td>{{ row.a }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.b }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.c }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </ng-template>
</table>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0HAIFO8YAW5EUDJ5p2g?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the solution it help a lot +1.